# Attaching a Picture to Word using ContentControl

Tags: c#, image, cpu-word, contentcontrol

I have a word template file within some content-control that one of them is a Picture-content-control, tagged with *sign*.
I read many documents and some questions like mines here and reached to some code like this one, but it just doesn't work and do not add the picture to document, I don't understand where is the problem.

```
 public void AddSignHidden(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document Doc, string SignImagePath)
        {

            ContentControls Ccontrol = Doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("__sign");

            foreach (ContentControl nativeControl in Ccontrol)
            {
                nativeControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(SignImagePath, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing);
            }

            Doc.Save();
            Doc.Close();
            Doc = null;

        }
```

Comment: You should reduce the code in your question to include only the parts that are needed. _”Just doesn’t work”_ is a useless description of the problem. Are you getting any errors? Have you traced the code and checked each step? There could be numerous reasons why it “just doesn’t work”, unfortunately only you can validate that things are actually happening. Example; have you checked to make sure the document is open and `Ccontrol` actually returned with at least 1 `ContenControl` item? It appears obvious that you should at the least be getting an error on the line… `oDoc.Save();`

Comment: @JohnG thanks for your answer, every line of my code works without any errors, my content- controls have one content-control with the type of picture. I just don't know why the result is not what I expected, and the document has not changed.I updated the code to be smaller.

Comment: In my tests, the code works as expected the first time, however, running it a second time appears to corrupt the file.